# Linux boot command to launch GUI

Tags: linux, boot

I've installed Linpus Linux (no dual boot) and all I see is this:

```
[root@localhost /]#
```

What line command do I use to launch the GUI?

Comment: What does `startx` get you?

Comment: Have you ever seen the GUI on this machine? Is this a new install?  What did you do before is started doing this?

Answer (score 4):

Reinstall with an easier / better version of Linux for your needs.  You might want to try Fedora if something similar is important to you, or alternatively Mint or Ubuntu.

You will probably find support for Linpus extremely limited as it is a fringe distribution (based on Fedora).   You might want to try the instructions at http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/13/html/Installation_Guide/sn-switching-to-gui-login.html  which basicallly boil down to

```
yum groupinstall "X Window System" XFCE
```

And then modifying the line "initdefault" in /etc/inittab to 1.

If you have problems following this instructions, XFCE is a lot less resource hungry then Gnome or KDE, and if you are using a lightweight PC (as your Distro might imply), you will want to use XFCE.   Also, if you don't know how to use vi, you might be able to use the editor "nano" or "pico" if its installed, it would be easier.